# como asegurarme de que terraform trabaje sobre el plan anterior en github actions?

Tags: aws, autocompletar, yml, pipeline, github-actions

este es mi pipeline.yml

name: Terraform-GitHub-Actions
on:
push:
branches: [ main ]
pull_request:
branches: [ main ]
env:
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.aws_access_key }}
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.aws_secret_key }}
jobs:
build:
name: build
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- name: Checkout
uses: actions/checkout@v2

```
  - name: Set up Terraform
    uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
  
  - name: Terraform Init
    id: init
    run: terraform init
  
  - name: Terraform Plan
    id: plan
    run: terraform plan
  
  - name: Terraform Apply
    id: apply
    run: terraform apply --auto-approve
```

Comment: Has intentado guardar el plan en el último paso y en la siguiente corrida ejecutarlo al inicio?

Answer (score 0):

`terraform plan` tiene la opción `-out` para guardar el plan en un archivo y pasarselo a `terraform apply`

```
  - name: Set up Terraform
    uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
  
  - name: Terraform Init
    id: init
    run: terraform init
  
  - name: Terraform Plan
    id: plan
    run: terraform plan -out plan-file
  
  - name: Terraform Apply
    id: apply
    run: terraform apply --auto-approve plan-file
```